# why the background color can't be assigned to the view

Tags: android, view, material-components-android

I have declared the white and black color value in color.xml file, trying to use that as the background color for the two given view but the view is accepting it.

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">` is my theme.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:backgroundTint="@color/black"`

Comment: You could have put this in the comment.